# Continuous errors with restaurant billing program

Tags: compiler-errors

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
//This program computes tax and tip on a restaurant bill.

public class RestaurantBill
{
   public static void main(String[] args)   {


   double charge;
   double tax = 0.0675;
   double tipRate = 0.15;
   double totalWithTax;
   double taxAmount;
   double tipAmount;
   double grandTotal;


   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("What is your name? ");
   name = keyboard.nextLine();
   System.out.print("Please enter the cost of your meal ");
   charge = keyboard.nextDouble();

   System.out.println("Hi there " + name "\n Your tax                                        is "                            +                        taxAmount "     \n     Your tip will be $" + tipAmount " /n and your total cost will be $" + grandTotal);
   }
}
```

and I get this error over and over...

```
  RestaurantBill2.java:24: error: ')' expected
  System.out.println("Hi there " + name "\n Your tax is " + taxAmount " \n Your tip will be $" + tipAmount " /n and your total cost will be $" + grandTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in string concatenation: add `+` after `name`, after `taxAmount` and after `tipAmount` in the line indicated in the error message.

Or split the line into several separate prints:

```
System.out.println("Hi there " + name);
System.out.println("\n Your tax is " + taxAmount);
System.out.println("\n Your tip will be $" + tipAmount);
System.out.println("/n and your total cost will be $" + grandTotal);
```

Check if you really need to print `\n` when using a function with **...ln** suffix.

You might also want to replace `/n` with `\n` and clean-up some spaces.
You certainly need to add some *tax* and *tip* calculations, too...

Comment: yeah the extra spaces added themselves when I transferred the code over to this site...don't know why that took place...but I re-wrote the whole thing...and now im getting a "variable has not been initialized" error...

Comment: That seems to deserve a separate question.